# SELinux blocking nginx -t

Tags: nginx, redhat, selinux, rocky-linux

I'm setting up Rocky Linux and I've run into this error:

```
sudo nginx -t

nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (13: Permission denied)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

My user's SELinux information is:

```
id -Z

staff_u:staff_r:staff_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
```

```
sudo -s
id -Z

staff_u:sysadm_r:sysadm_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
```

My sudoer rule:

```
USERNAME ALL=(ALL) ROLE=sysadm_r TYPE=sysadm_t NOPASSWD: ALL
```

I have followed https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/9/html/using_selinux/managing-confined-and-unconfined-users_using-selinux#confining-an-administrator-using-sudo-and-the-sysadm_r-role_managing-confined-and-unconfined-users.

After having trouble getting any errors logged, I disabled the 'dontaudit' rules and got:

```
ausearch -m AVC,USER_AVC,SELINUX_ERR,USER_SELINUX_ERR -ts recent

time->Fri Oct  6 17:02:35 2023
type=PROCTITLE msg=audit(1696611755.583:1149): proctitle=7375646F006E67696E78002D74
type=PATH msg=audit(1696611755.583:1149): item=0 name="/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2" inode=8668 dev=fd:02 mode=0100755 ouid=0 ogid=0 rdev=00:00 obj=system_u:object_r:ld_so_t:s0 nametype=NORMAL cap_fp=0 cap_fi=0 cap_fe=0 cap_fver=0 cap_frootid=0
type=CWD msg=audit(1696611755.583:1149): cwd="/home/USERNAME"
type=EXECVE msg=audit(1696611755.583:1149): argc=3 a0="sudo" a1="nginx" a2="-t"
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1696611755.583:1149): arch=c000003e syscall=59 success=yes exit=0 a0=56233d0695a0 a1=56233d1800a0 a2=56233cffae40 a3=8 items=1 ppid=6128 pid=11286 auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=1000 sgid=1000 fsgid=1000 tty=pts0 ses=3 comm="sudo" exe="/usr/bin/sudo" subj=staff_u:staff_r:staff_sudo_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 key=(null)
type=AVC msg=audit(1696611755.583:1149): avc:  denied  { siginh } for  pid=11286 comm="sudo" scontext=staff_u:staff_r:staff_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=staff_u:staff_r:staff_sudo_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tclass=process permissive=0
type=AVC msg=audit(1696611755.583:1149): avc:  denied  { rlimitinh } for  pid=11286 comm="sudo" scontext=staff_u:staff_r:staff_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=staff_u:staff_r:staff_sudo_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tclass=process permissive=0
type=AVC msg=audit(1696611755.583:1149): avc:  denied  { noatsecure } for  pid=11286 comm="bash" scontext=staff_u:staff_r:staff_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=staff_u:staff_r:staff_sudo_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tclass=process permissive=0
```

It seems to be running as

```
staff_u:staff_r:staff_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
```

and not

```
staff_u:sysadm_r:sysadm_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
```

I'm far from an expert when it comes to this so any help is greatly appreciated!

---

As requested:

```
audit2allow -a

#============= chkpwd_t ==============
allow chkpwd_t user_devpts_t:chr_file { read write };

#============= init_t ==============
allow init_t unconfined_service_t:process siginh;

#============= staff_sudo_t ==============
allow staff_sudo_t chkpwd_t:process { noatsecure rlimitinh siginh };
allow staff_sudo_t self:capability net_admin;
allow staff_sudo_t shadow_t:file read;
allow staff_sudo_t sysadm_t:process { noatsecure rlimitinh siginh };

#============= staff_t ==============
allow staff_t staff_sudo_t:process { noatsecure rlimitinh siginh };

#============= sysadm_t ==============
allow sysadm_t http_port_t:tcp_socket name_bind;
```

```
sudo ls -Z /etc/nginx

system_u:object_r:httpd_config_t:s0 conf.d
system_u:object_r:httpd_config_t:s0 fastcgi_params
system_u:object_r:httpd_config_t:s0 mime.types
system_u:object_r:httpd_config_t:s0 modules
system_u:object_r:httpd_config_t:s0 nginx.conf
system_u:object_r:httpd_config_t:s0 scgi_params
system_u:object_r:httpd_config_t:s0 uwsgi_params
```

```
sudo ls -Z /etc/nginx/conf.d

system_u:object_r:httpd_config_t:s0 default.conf
```

Comment: Hi, can you edit your question with the result of `audit2allow -a` please?

Comment: Sure, that's done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your setup is working correctly, and your `staff_u` user running a command preprended with `sudo` is indeed running with `sysadm_r` role.

Here, your error `nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (13: Permission denied)` and the audit log `allow sysadm_t http_port_t:tcp_socket name_bind;` does show that you have a denial because the type `sysadm_t` cannot `name_bind` the port `http_port_t:tcp_socket`, here the port tcp/80.

To allow this behaviour, you can create a policy:

```bash
cat > sysadm_bind_http.te << EOF
module sysadm_bind_http 1.0;

require {
type sysadm_t;
type http_port_t;
class tcp_socket { name_bind };
}

#============= sysadm_t ==============
allow sysadm_t http_port_t:tcp_socket name_bind;
EOF
checkmodule -M -m -o sysadm_bind_http.mod sysadm_bind_http.te
semodule_package -o sysadm_bind_http.pp -m sysadm_bind_http.mod
semodule -i sysadm_bind_http.pp
```

Comment: I like this but I'd suggest if doing it properly a type transition since it tests in the `httpd_t` domain (which is what you want) and avoids you having to give potentially privileged capabilities to `staff_t` directly. Something like `apache_domtrans(...)` and a `role staff_r types http_exec_t`. Oddly the macro for this doesn't include the role in it itself (which is weird for selinux)

Answer (score 0):

On Red Hat-based systems, such as Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) or CentOS, SELinux (Security-Enhanced Linux) can also sometimes block `nginx -t` due to policy violations or incorrect security labels. To troubleshoot and resolve this issue on Red Hat systems.

Here are the steps to troubleshoot and resolve SELinux issues with `nginx -t` on Red Hat-based systems:

1. **Check SELinux Audit Logs:**

   Review SELinux audit logs to gain more insights into why `nginx -t` is being blocked. You can use the `ausearch` command:

   ```bash
   sudo ausearch -c 'nginx' --raw | audit2allow -M my-nginx-policy
   sudo semodule -i my-nginx-policy.pp
   ```

   This generates a custom SELinux policy module based on the audit logs and installs it.
2. **Check Nginx Configuration Files:**

   Ensure that the Nginx configuration files have the correct SELinux security context labels using the `ls -Z` command. If labels are incorrect, use `chcon` to set the correct labels:

   ```bash
   sudo chcon -t httpd_config_t /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
   ```

   Replace `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` with the actual path to your Nginx configuration file.
3. **Test Nginx Configuration:**

   After addressing any SELinux policy issues and verifying the security labels, try running `nginx -t` to check the configuration syntax:

   ```bash
   sudo nginx -t
   ```

   SELinux should no longer block this operation if the issues have been resolved.
4. **Relabel the Entire Nginx Configuration Directory (if necessary):**

   If you have multiple Nginx configuration files with incorrect security labels, you can recursively relabel the entire directory:

   ```bash
   sudo restorecon -Rv /etc/nginx/
   ```

   This command resets SELinux security context labels for all files and directories under `/etc/nginx/`.
5. **SELinux Policy Modification (if necessary):**

   If SELinux continues to block the operation despite taking the above steps, you may need to create a custom SELinux policy module specifically for your Nginx configuration. Be cautious when modifying SELinux policies, as it can impact system security.

Remember to follow SELinux best practices and only modify policies when you fully understand the consequences. Additionally, regularly updating your system and keeping SELinux policies up-to-date can help avoid issues like this in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Step 1 worked and allowed me to run sudo nginx -t, but like you say, I have no idea what it did so I'm cautious about relying on that. I've added the results for Step 2 to my question. It's a clean install of nginx on a clean install of Rocky and it looks fine to me

Comment: Then I would suggest to do some research about it by reading the documentation. That's also how I do if I don't know something. I have been in IT for 15 years and when someone gave me advice in my early career I googled a lot and read the docs. A clean install using a package manager or configure and build? By installing you sometimes have options so saying clean install doesn't matter much. If you are installing using a package manager, the package creator could have made a mistake when he created the package

Comment: It's a VPS so I choose my distro (Rocky 9) and that's about it. All I'm doing is installing the stable version of nginx from their repo using dnf and following the RedHat guide I linked, so there's nothing crazy going on and I would have thought lots of people before me would have tried this combination.

This has been bothering me for a while and I'm running out of things to read, hence turning to experts.

Comment: You said with the first thing I don't know what I'm doing, and for that one I meant do some research. You can also search the sexlinux audit logs with `ausearch -m AVC,USER_AVC -ts recent` to maybe get some information why the policy blocked it.

Comment: Since you mentioned VPS provider, did you selected your distribution and then it got installed for you, and did you directly installed from an iso or other installation binaries?

Comment: Yeah, installed for me. I'm using Vultr so they provision the VPS and then hand me the keys. I'm not sure which source they use, I just pick between version 8 or 9. I've got the output of ausearch in my question. It doesn't mean much to me but I'll do some more digging

Comment: Then it's not a clean install, they might have created an modified installation image where the sexlinux policy is modified.if you can open a support case to them